# Set DTR, RTS, CTS, DSR and Xonn/Xoff on SerialPort

Tags: c#, c++, serial-port

I have this C++ code which I need to translate to C#.

```
 *hDev = CreateFile(PortNameUNC, GENERIC_READ|GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, 
      OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);

 if(*hDev == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) return false ;

DCB *dcb = new DCB ;
memset(dcb, 0x00, sizeof(DCB)) ;
dcb->DCBlength       = sizeof(DCB);
dcb->BaudRate        = BaudRate;
dcb->Parity          = Parity;
dcb->StopBits        = StopBits;
dcb->ByteSize        = ByteSize;
dcb->fBinary         = TRUE;
dcb->fDsrSensitivity = 0;
dcb->fDtrControl     = (DTR ? DTR_CONTROL_ENABLE : DTR_CONTROL_DISABLE) ;
dcb->fRtsControl     = (RTS ? RTS_CONTROL_ENABLE : RTS_CONTROL_DISABLE) ;
dcb->fOutxCtsFlow    = (CTS ? 1 : 0) ;
dcb->fOutxDsrFlow    = (DSR ? 1 : 0) ;
dcb->fOutX           = (XonnXoff ? 1 : 0) ;
dcb->fInX            = 0 ;
```

I managed to translate most of it on C# using e.g.

```
    m_port = new SerialPort(portName, baudRate, parity, dataBits, stopBits);
```

But I am not sure how to set properties like `DTR, RTS, CTS, DSR and Xonn/Xoff?`

I found `Dtr.Enable` and `Rts.Enable` properties on `SerialPort`, but what to do with other three?  CTS, DSR and Xonn/Xoff? How to enable them?

---

EDIT: Also, here is my C# implementation of above. **Have I correctly mapped the C++ code to C# as below? any feedback appreciated.** especially the `xon/xoff` flags and the `dtr` and `rts`?

```
 public SerialPortHASP(string portName, int baudRate, Parity parity, int dataBits, StopBits stopBits, bool dtr, bool rts, bool xonxoff)
    {

        m_port = new SerialPort(portName, baudRate, parity, dataBits, stopBits);

        // Set XonXoff if set
        if (xonxoff)
            m_port.Handshake = Handshake.XOnXOff;

        // Set DTR/RTS
        m_port.DtrEnable = dtr;
        m_port.RtsEnable = rts;

        // Open the port for communications
        m_port.Open();
    }
```

Comment: @Hans Passant: why did you remove your answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CTS and DSR are inputs so they can't be set from code.  They can be checked by accessing the following properties;  CtsHolding and DsrHolding.

XOnXOff is a flow control and can be set using the serial ports Handshake property.

Comment: "CTS and DSR are inputs so they can't be set from code" - I see, but how come they can be set using the C++ code I posted?

Comment: PS. do you see anything in that C++ code I might additionally need to replicate in my C# code? (like communication properties etc.) as I understand XonXoff is for software flow control. The others like CTS, are for hardware flow control